# Could not find a declaration file for module 'module-name'. '/path/to/module-name.js' implicitly has an 'any' type

Tags: typescript, node-modules

I read how TypeScript [module resolution](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html) works.

I have the following repository: [@ts-stack/di](https://github.com/ts-stack/di).
After compiling the directory structure is as follows:

```
├── dist
│   ├── annotations.d.ts
│   ├── annotations.js
│   ├── index.d.ts
│   ├── index.js
│   ├── injector.d.ts
│   ├── injector.js
│   ├── profiler.d.ts
│   ├── profiler.js
│   ├── providers.d.ts
│   ├── providers.js
│   ├── util.d.ts
│   └── util.js
├── LICENSE
├── package.json
├── README.md
├── src
│   ├── annotations.ts
│   ├── index.ts
│   ├── injector.ts
│   ├── profiler.ts
│   ├── providers.ts
│   └── util.ts
└── tsconfig.json
```

In my package.json I wrote `"main": "dist/index.js"`.

In Node.js everything works fine, but TypeScript:

```
import {Injector} from '@ts-stack/di';
```

> Could not find a declaration file for module '@ts-stack/di'. '/path/to/node_modules/@ts-stack/di/dist/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.

And yet, if I import as follows, then everything works:

```
import {Injector} from '/path/to/node_modules/@ts-stack/di/dist/index.js';
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For people who are looking for a place to easily find type definitions, you can use official TypeScript type search: https://www.typescriptlang.org/dt/search?search=

Comment: @MohammadKermani "This page is no longer necessary.

The npm and Yarn package registries now include type information for packages."

Answer (score 202, accepted):

#### For the situation where you are installing your own npm package

If you're using a third party package, see [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42505940/1716560).

Remove `.js` from `"main": "dist/index.js"` in `package.json`.

```json
"main": "dist/index",
```

Also add [`types` in `package.json` per the TypeScript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/publishing.html):

```json
"main": "dist/index",
"types": "dist/index",
```

The folder `dist` is where the TS compiler stores your module's files.

Comment: I was struggling a little with this: When you have your own package, be sure to remove old contents of `dist` folder of your package (or whole `node_modules` in your project) and run your bundler again. Even after this edit, I still had old `index.js` in `dist` which caused the warning for me.

Comment: Thanks for this - your English wasn't very clear but this helped, my `typings` was incorrect.  I've made a few changes to make the answer clearer.

Comment: @optimista I had trouble with stale dist too. ```rm -rf ./dist/* ; tsc```

Comment: In my case what really worked was: `"main": "dist/index.js", "typings": "src/index"`.

Answer (score 1000):

Here are two other solutions

When a module is not yours - try to install types from `@types`:

```
npm install -D @types/module-name
```

If the above install errors - try changing `import` statements to `require`:

```
// import * as yourModuleName from 'module-name';
const yourModuleName = require('module-name');
```

Comment: If you get could not find name require run this for TypeScript 2.0: `npm install @types/node --save-dev`

Comment: What if module doesn't have @types package?

Comment: @DanielKmak, it's library of typescript definitions.

Comment: Example usage:

`const mdbreact = require('mdbreact');

const { Button, Card, CardBody, CardText, CardTitle, CardImage } = mdbreact;`

Comment: notable: you need to do this in addition to installing the base package (had this issue with sinon)

Comment: I am using react typescript project with YARN, only require worked. Thank you
  ```const yourModuleName = require('module-name');```

Comment: @DanielKmak I have the same question. Looks like just using require instead works. But FYI: There's a repo called DefinitelyTyped (mentioned in another answer below) that can provide types if what you are importing is popular enough.

Comment: yarn version: `yarn add --dev @types/module-name` ... if your packages has `@types`

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me! Why does it happen though?

Comment: What if a module is yours? What to do with that module so that it does not offer this issue after published?

Answer (score 744):

If you're importing a third-party module `'foo'` that doesn't provide any typings, either in the library itself, or in the `@types/foo` package (generated from the [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) repository), then you can make this error go away by declaring the module in a file with a `.d.ts` extension. TypeScript looks for `.d.ts` files in the same places that it will look for normal `.ts` files: as specified under "files", "include", and "exclude" in the `tsconfig.json`.

```js
// foo.d.ts
declare module 'foo';
```

Then when you import `foo` it'll just be typed as `any`.

---

Alternatively, if you want to roll your own typings you can do that too:

```js
// foo.d.ts
declare module 'foo' {
    export function getRandomNumber(): number
}
```

Then this will compile correctly:

```js
import { getRandomNumber } from 'foo';
const x = getRandomNumber(); // x is inferred as number
```

You don't have to provide full typings for the module, just enough for the bits that you're actually using (and want proper typings for), so it's particularly easy to do if you're using a fairly small amount of API.

---

On the other hand, if you don't care about the typings of external libraries and want all libraries without typings to be imported as `any`, you can add this to a file with a `.d.ts` extension:

```js
declare module '*';
```

The benefit (and downside) of this is that you can import absolutely anything and TS will compile.

Comment: where does the compiler look for `d.ts` files? should you provide any config such as `typeRoots`?

Comment: @Tom It looks for `.d.ts` files in the same places that it will look for normal `.ts` files: as specified "files", "include", and "exclude" in the `tsconfig.json`.   I would not recommend using `typeRoots` for this purpose: that's intended for the location of external type modules (i.e. `node_modules/@types`), not individual `.d.ts` files.

Comment: In order for this to work, I had to make `declare module '...'` the first line of code in the `module.d.ts` file, and include any imports inside the module block as opposed to before it. Before I did that, the compiler was saying that it couldn't find the module.

Comment: Will `declare module '*'` ensure that only packages without typings are compiled or will it interfere with packages that do have typings at all?

Comment: If you are getting such error when using `ts-node`, please have a look on ts-node docs [Help! My Types Are Missing!](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node#help-my-types-are-missing). I've spent several hours trying to find out why compiler does not see my `.d.ts`.

Comment: When using ES6Modules do not forget to use export:
  export declare module 'foo';

Comment: Using Angular 11, the `files` and `include` seem to be in `tsconfig.app.json`, not `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: If the module is a default export, remove `export` keyword before function definition and add the following line after function: `export = getRandomNumber`

Comment: The link that @vitalets posted was broken for me. Here it is: https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/866

Answer (score 422):

If you need a quick fix, simply add this before the line of your import:

```
// @ts-ignore
```

Comment: This causes an error in later versions of eslint: `error  Do not use "// @ts-ignore" comments because they suppress compilation errors  @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-ignore`

Comment: @Hykilpikonna I believe you can add /`* eslint-disable */` to disable eslint before you use  `// @ts-ignore` and then add `/* eslint-enable */` after your problem line of code to re-enable eslint for the rest of your file.

Comment: You can also add `// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment` before the ts line

Comment: This isn't is a fix or an answer, but rather a way of suppressing the complaint.

Comment: It is a fix when you want to go bed and just get it deployed.

Answer (score 98):

For anyone else reading this, try renaming your .js file to .ts

Edit:
You can also add `"allowJs": true` to your tsconfig file.

Comment: I have set `allowJs` to `true` but it does not work

Comment: The easiest solution imho. Though I wonder if there are any implications to setting allowsJS to true. It seems it was set to false by default.

Answer (score 94):

TypeScript is basically implementing rules and adding types to your code to make it more clear and more accurate due to the lack of constraints in Javascript. TypeScript requires you to describe your data, so that the compiler can check your code and find errors. The compiler will let you know if you are using mismatched types, if you are out of your scope or you try to return a different type.
So, when you are using external libraries and modules with TypeScript, they need to contain files that describe the types in that code. Those files are called **type declaration files** with an extension `d.ts`. Most of the declaration types for npm modules are already written and you can include them using `npm install @types/module_name` (where module_name is the name of the module whose types you wanna include).

However, there are modules that don't have their type definitions and in order to make the error go away and import the module using `import * as module_name from 'module-name'`, create a folder `typings` in the root of your project, inside create a new folder with your module name and in that folder create a `module_name.d.ts` file and write `declare module 'module_name'`. After this just go to your `tsconfig.json` file and add `"typeRoots": [ "../../typings", "../../node_modules/@types"]` in the `compilerOptions` (with the proper relative path to your folders) to let TypeScript know where it can find the types definitions of your libraries and modules and add a new property `"exclude": ["../../node_modules", "../../typings"]` to the file. 
Here is an example of how your tsconfig.json file should look like:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "../dst/",
        "target": "ESNEXT",
        "typeRoots": [
            "../../typings",
            "../../node_modules/@types"
        ]
    },
    "lib": [
            "es2016"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "../../node_modules",
        "../../typings"
    ]
}
```

By doing this, the error will go away and you will be able to stick to the latest ES6 and TypeScript rules.

Comment: It only worked for me if I named the typings file `index.d.ts`. Other than that, this was the only solution that worked all round for me.

Comment: Also worked for me (didn't need to change the name to `index.d.ts`). For those who are using the default app structure of `ng new app-name`, you will probably need your paths to have one level, like this: `"../node_modules"` and `"../typings"`, etc. Also, make sure that the `module-name` part in  `declare module 'module_name'` statement is exactly the same as the way you are importing it in your original file. For example: in my case, it needed to be: `declare module 'videojs-record/dist/videojs.record.js'`, because that's how I was importing it in the original file.

Comment: If I have one folder (where my app/components live) in `"include"` in my tsconfig.json file which is different than where the `typings` folder lives then I shouldn't need to add the `"excludes":...` part right?

Answer (score 57):

This way works for me:

##### 1. add your own declaration in a declaration file such as index.d.ts(maybe under the project root)

```
declare module 'Injector';
```

##### 2. add your index.d.ts to tsconfig.json

```
  {
    "compilerOptions": {
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "jsx": "react",
        "noUnusedParameters": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports":true,
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "ES2015",
        "declaration": true,
        "outDir": "./lib",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "importHelpers": true
      },
      "include": [
        "src/**/*",
        "index.d.ts",   // declaration file path
      ],
      "compileOnSave": false
    }
```

Comment: This solved it for me. I also added a folder named `typings` in my project root. Inside I added the `.d.ts` file

Comment: doesn't works with react-bootstrap elements

Comment: Unknown compiler option 'include'.  Oh right, this is outside of compilerOptions, that is what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 36):

Unfortunately it's out of our hands whether the package writer bothers with a declaration file. What I tend to do is have a file such `index.d.ts` that'll contain all the missing declaration files from various packages:

**Index.d.ts:**

```
declare module 'v-tooltip';
declare module 'parse5';
declare module 'emoji-mart-vue-fast';
```

and reference it to in your `tsconfig.js`:

```
"include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.tsx",
    "index.d.ts" // this
  ]
```

Answer (score 26):

Just create a file named `typings.d.ts` in the root directory of your project.
Inside this file just add `declare module <module_name>`. Here, `module_name` can be any module's name that you want to import. Finally, open the `tsconfig.json` file and include the file `typings.d.ts` inside the array named as `include array`.

```
// typings.d.ts 
declare module 'abc-module';

// tsconfig.json 
{
  ...
"include": [
    "src", "typings.d.ts"
  ]
}

// BOOM, Problem solved!!!
```

This technique provides your module with a type named "any".
For more info: https://medium.com/@steveruiz/using-a-javascript-library-without-type-declarations-in-a-typescript-project-3643490015f3

Answer (score 20):

This worked for me.

```
// modules.d.ts 
declare module 'my-module';
```

```
// tsconfig.json 
{
  ...
  "include": [
    ...
    "src", "modules.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

```
// Import
import * as MyModule from 'my-module'
...
const theModule = MyModule()
...
```

Answer (score 15):

This is the way I made it to work.

In my case I used a library that doesn't have types defined: `react-mobile-datepicker`

a. Create a folder inside `/src`. In my case I used this path: `/src/typings/`.

b. Create a `.d.ts` file. For my example: `/src/typings/react-mobile-datepicker.d.ts`

c. I used the following code to extend its properties and making it type safe:

```
declare module 'react-mobile-datepicker' {
  class DatePicker extends React.Component<DatePickerProps, any> {}

  interface DatePickerProps {
    isPopup?: boolean;
    theme?: string;
    dateConfig?: DatePickerConfig;
  }

  export interface DatePickerConfig {
    prop1: number;
    pro2: string;
  }
  export default DatePicker;
}
```

d. Import your types as you would normally do where you are using the 3rd party library.

```
import DatePicker, { DatePickerConfig, DatePickerConfigDate } from 'react-mobile-datepicker';
```

e. Change `tsconfig.json` and add this piece of code:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    //...other properties
    "typeRoots": [
      "src/typings",
      "node_modules/@types"
    ]
  }}
```

Links to articles that I used as a source:

https://templecoding.com/blog/2016/03/31/creating-typescript-typings-for-existing-react-components

https://www.credera.com/insights/typescript-adding-custom-type-definitions-for-existing-libraries

Answer (score 8):

Solution: All you have to do is edit your TypeScript Config file `tsconfig.json` and add a new key-value pair as

```
"compilerOptions": {
"noImplicitAny": false
}
```

Comment: Won't this just remove the error messages instead of solving the issue?

Comment: This will have much broader impacts to your typescript type checking than just making this import work.  Proceed with caution and read up on this setting to make sure you want all the side effects.

Comment: If you find yourself turning this off, you might as well run in javascript. The other options in this answer are much better alternatives. Sure, any types gives you a way to morph objects and stuff round pegs into square holes, but you lost knowledge about what input to expect. You can add type guards, however with no any this is done at transpile time, type guards are done at runtime.

Answer (score 6):

A simple fix:

```
// example.d.ts
declare module 'foo';
```

If you want to declare an interface of an object (Recommended for big projects) you may use :

```
// example.d.ts
declare module 'foo'{
    // example
    export function getName(): string
}
```

How to use that? simple..

```
const x = require('foo') // or import x from 'foo'
x.getName() // intellisense can read this
```

Answer (score 6):

Check the `"tsconfig.json"` file for compilation options `"include"` and `"exclude"`. If it does not exist, just add them by informing your ***root*** directory.

```
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
  ...
  "include": [
    "src", 
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules", 
  ]
}
```

I solved my silly problem just by removing the extension statement `"*.spec.ts"` from the `"exclude"`, because when including the `"import"` in these files, there were always problems.

Answer (score 6):

In most cases you would likely install a types package for your dependency, either way you could add allowJs -> true in your tsconfig.json file

Comment: I faced this issue with `express.js`, after installing `@types/express` it was solved.

Answer (score 5):

If you have installed the module and still getting the error, a short and sweet solution is to ignore the error message by adding the following line above that line

```
// @ts-ignore: Unreachable code error
```

Answer (score 5):

The answers from @ktretyak and @Retsam are correct but I would like to add a complete real time example and what I had to do:

Error:

> Error TS7016  (TS) Could not find a declaration file for module
> 'react-region-select'.
>
> 'C:/Repo/node_modules/react-region-select/lib/RegionSelect.js'
> implicitly has an 'any' type.
>
> Try `npm i --save-dev @types/react-region-select` if it exists or add a new declaration
> (.d.ts) file containing `declare module

Running `npm i --save-dev @types/react-region-select` gives the error:

> npm ERR! code E404
>
> npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@types%2freact-region-select - Not found
>
> npm ERR! 404  '@types/react-region-select@latest' is not
> in the npm registry.
>
> npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
>
> npm ERR! 404 Note that you
> can also install from a npm tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

Given that `create-react-app` creates a file called `react-app-env.d.ts` I tried to put `declare module 'react-region-select';` in there but I still received the error.

I then created a new folder in `src` called `typings` and a file called `react-region-select.d.ts`. In there I declared the module like this:

```
declare module 'react-region-select';
```

After doing it like this the error disappeared and I could import it like the documentation states:

```
import RegionSelect from "react-region-select";
```

https://github.com/casavi/react-region-select

Answer (score 5):

In my case, 3 different ways of resolving this issue are all not working. Once you set "type" as "module" in package.json then it will comply with ES Module instead of CommonJS syntax. I was able to resolve this by using ES Module syntax according to my package.json settings.

```
import ws from 'ws'

export const create = (/** @type {string} */ accessToken) => {
    const WebSocket = ws;
    return new WebSocket(endpoint, accessToken, sslOptions);
}
```

This way you are able to use the WebSocket class in 'ws' module. It's an example of a node module but you can basically put any type of node module and the functions in it.

Those are **NOT** working for me below:

1. `npm install -D @types/module-name`
2. `const foo = require('module-name');`
3. 

```
// index.d.ts
declare module 'foo';
```

4. configurations from tsconfig.json

```
"noImplicitAny": true,
"allowJs": true
```

Answer (score 4):

I've tried everything here, but for me it was a completely different issue:
I had to remove from my `*.d.ts` any import statements:

```
import { SomeModuleType } from '3rd-party-module';
```

After removing the error went away...

**Clarification**:
When we declare a module in a `*.d.ts` file, it's automatically picked up by the Typescript compiler as an *ambient* module (the one you don't need to import explicitly). Once we specify the `import ... from ...`, the file now becomes a normal (ES6) module, and hence won't be picked up automatically. Hence if you still want it to behave as an *ambient* module, use a different import style like so:

```
type MyType: import('3rd-party-module').SomeModuleType;
```

Comment: That's a dynamic import and returns a promise... it would only work in an Async context. Good thing to know though.

Comment: In effect, if you follow any of the other upvoted answers to this question, but there happens to be a normal "import" in your *.d.ts file, then your *.d.ts file will be silently ignored.

Answer (score 4):

I was facing the same problem with many packages in many projects. So i created [Declarator](https://github.com/ArthurFiorette/declarator), a npm package that generate type declarations automatically.

It basically works by running `tsc --emitDeclarationOnly` in the background.

You can install it from npm:

```
npm install --save-dev declarator
yarn add -D declarator
```

Then create a simple `declarator.json` file:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ArthurFiorette/declarator/master/schema.json",
  "packages": ["package1","package2"]
}
```

And create a script to run it:

*Using postinstall script will run it on every package installation, may be useful*

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "declarator"
  }
}
```

It won't generate powerful types and you'll probably encounter many `any` types along the way, but it's much better with than without

Read more: https://github.com/ArthurFiorette/declarator#readme

Answer (score 3):

I was getting this too, had me baffled for a while, even with the module and types already installed and reloading my IDE several times.

What fixed it in my case was terminating terminal processes, removing `node_modules`, clearing the node package manager cache and doing a fresh `install` then re-loading the editor.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue using a node module with a react application written in typescript. The module was successfully installed using `npm i --save my-module`.
It is written in javascript and exports a `Client` class.

With:

```
import * as MyModule from 'my-module';
let client: MyModule.Client = new MyModule.Client();
```

Compilation fails with the error:

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'my-module'. 
'[...]/node_modules/my-module/lib/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/my-module` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'my-module';`
```

`@types/my-module` does not exist, so I added a `my-module.d.ts` file next to the one where `my-module` is imported, with the suggested line. I then got the error:

```
Namespace '"my-module"' has no exported member 'Client'.
```

The client is actually exported and works normally if I use it in a js app. Also, the previous message tells me that the compiler is looking in the right file (`/node_modules/my-module/lib/index.js` is defined in `my-module/package.json` `"main"` element).

I solved the issue by telling the compiler I do not care about implicit `any`, that is, I set to `false` the following line of the `tsconfig.json` file:

```
    "noImplicitAny": false,
```

Comment: I mean, this works but you're losing the ability to strictly type the rest of your code. It's not a great workaround.

Answer (score 3):

If you are seeing this error in **Webstorm**, and you just installed the package, you might need to **restart the typescript service** before it will pick it up.

- Open the help menu
- Find an action
- Search for `Restart Typescript Service`

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you have typescript configured with "old" `moduleResolution`. If you edit `tsconfig.json` to have `moduleResolution: "nodenext"`, it will correctly find the types from the `package.json` definitions.

Unfortunately, that will probably cause a lot of headache in your current repo.

Therefore you can use this workaround:

*Add a re-exporting `.ts` file for every entry that isn't in the exact path that TS thinks it is.*

So in your case, you would add `/index.ts` to your package (yes, with the `.ts` extension, do not convert to `.js`), and it should contain simply

```
// Stub to make TS happy. Do not add an extension to the import!
export * from "./dist"
```

The path you're re-exporting should not have extensions, so that TS will try resolving it and will find the `index.d.ts` types file that's connected to it. If your types file is not named in a way that TS will find it when importing from the javascript, you have to rename it.

If you are creating a package with [exports](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#subpath-exports), the same thing applies. Suppose you have an export `/vite` which loads from `/dist/vite.mjs`, you have to add the file `/vite/index.ts` which does `export * from "../dist/vite"`. Only TS will read this file.

Answer (score 2):

You may need create the file with `.d.ts` extension.

push this file name under `include` key of `tsconfig.json` file:

```
  "include": [
    "src",
    "index.d.ts"
  ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Building on [Retsam's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50516783/13142325), you can also use wildcards (`*`) in `yourDeclarations.d.ts` file. For example, if you're trying to import a file, such as a `.css` or `.webp` file, you can place a `*` at the beginning of the file type declaration. It'd look something like this ⤵︎

```
declare module '*.webp';
```

Now you can import all the `.webp` files you'd like without any linting errors.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, adding ***paths*** alias worked and typescript found the declaration file:

```
// tsconfig.json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        ...
        paths: {
            "*": ["@types/*"]
        }
    }
}
```

And then add declaration files you need to *@types/* folder:

```
declare module 'not-found-module' {
    // your declations
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What works for me is installed the dependencies as dev dependencies. Above solution of disabling implicit type checking works but that kept me away from getting advantage of strictly typed code. So what you have to do is to just append the all the @types module installation with --save-dev flag.

Answer (score 1):

just run this command and will solve the problem

npm install --save @types/node-forge

more info in the next link

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/node-forge

Comment: That only works for the package node-forge though

Answer (score 0):

If import is not working for you

```
import * as html2pdf from 'html2pdf.js';
```

Comment the code, keep the below script file in index.html as given in the official docs.

```
<script src="https://rawgit.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf/master/dist/html2pdf.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

And declare the html2pdf variable in the component you are using it.

```
declare var html2pdf: any;
```

That's it. I was stuck in this issue for 2 days, but finally got it resolved.

Answer (score 0):

create the file with an arbitrary name and `.d.ts` extension.

ex: `index.d.ts`

push this file name under `include` key of `tsconfig.json` file:

```
  "include": [
    "src",
    "index.d.ts"
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

From the Typescript documentation:

> Note that the **"typings"** field is synonymous with **"types"**, and could be used as well.

> Also note that if your main declaration file is named **index.d.ts** and lives at the root of the package (next to index.js) **you do not need to mark the types property**, though it is advisable to do so.

For some reason my "types" property was pointing to some main.d.ts. Removed the line from the package.json and it started working.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem with uuid module in angular project.

Definitely not for prod, but putting '// @ts-ignore' on the previous line has quickly "solved" my problem.

[image]

Comment: suppressing ts errors won't fix the problem with types inferring

Comment: well this did work for me

Comment: In my case, there were no TS types for the package I was using and I think this is a fine way if not the best to fix it.

Answer (score -2):

Nobody mentioned here, but my solution was a simple restart in the last time I encountered this problem.

- Stop the npm start process
- Again, run command `npm start`
  and it started working.

Answer (score -2):

Just add `// @ts-ignore` before import like that:

```
// @ts-ignore
import replace from 'replace'
```

Comment: If you do this, you lose type checking. If you really can't get a fixed package or separate @types/replace definition, you could import it in a wrapper file and re-export with proper types added by you.

Answer (score -3):

for people who are getting this error in React, in tsconfig.json, set

```
"compilerOptions" : {
  ...
  "strict": false,
  ...
}
```

the auto-generated config from React's create-react-app has that flag set to true

Comment: Any downside with `strict:false`?

Comment: this hotfix worked for me

Answer (score -4):

All you have to do is edit your TypeScript Config file (tsconfig.json) and add a new key-value pair as
"noImplicitAny": false

Comment: This would nullify the benefits of using Typescript. You're basically silencing the warning instead of fixing it

Answer (score -8):

```
import { io, Socket,SocketIOClient } from 'socket.io-client';
```

Adding this on top of component.ts worked in my case.

Answer (score -13):

Simply you can import it using require as following code:

```
var _ = require('your_module_name');
```