# Could not find a declaration file for module 'vue-tabulator'

Tags: typescript, vue.js, tabulator

I am trying to use the vue-tabulator Vue component: https://github.com/angeliski/vue-tabulator in a simple Vue application which happens to be coded in TypeScript.

`main.ts`:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueTabulator from 'vue-tabulator'
import App from './App.vue'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

Vue.use(VueTabulator)

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

`App.ts`:

```
import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator'

@Component
export default class App extends Vue {}
```

`App.vue`:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <h1>Kewl</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<style scoped>
</style>

<script lang="ts" src="./App.ts">
</script>
```

When running my application with `npm run serve` I have the following:

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                                                                                                     2:23:19 PM
This dependency was not found:

* tabulator-tables in ./node_modules/vue-tabulator/dist/vue-tabulator.common.js

To install it, you can run: npm install --save tabulator-tables
Type checking in progress...
ERROR in C:/Users/eperret/Desktop/tabulator-tests/src/main.ts(2,26):
2:26 Could not find a declaration file for module 'vue-tabulator'. 'C:/Users/eperret/Desktop/tabulator-tests/node_modules/vue-tabulator/dist/vue-tabulator.umd.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/vue-tabulator` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'vue-tabulator';`
    1 | import Vue from 'vue'
  > 2 | import VueTabulator from 'vue-tabulator'
      |                          ^
    3 | import App from './App.vue'
    4 | 
    5 | Vue.config.productionTip = false
Version: typescript 3.5.3
Time: 3055ms
```

and last but not least, `packages.json`:

```
{
  "name": "tabulator-tests",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.3.2",
    "vue": "^2.6.10",
    "vue-class-component": "^7.0.2",
    "vue-property-decorator": "^8.3.0",
    "vue-tabulator": "^1.2.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^4.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^4.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "^4.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^4.0.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-standard": "^4.0.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.0.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "@vue/standard",
      "@vue/typescript"
    ],
    "rules": {},
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser"
    }
  },
  "postcss": {
    "plugins": {
      "autoprefixer": {}
    }
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions"
  ]
}
```

I check the answer given here: [Could not find a declaration file for module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42940920/could-not-find-a-declaration-file-for-module)

But I don't see how the solution given in that thread can actually help me.

How can I do?

[EDIT 1]

I tried to install the TypeScript types for `vue-tabulator` but it seems there isn't such a package:

```
npm install @types/vue-tabulator
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@types%2fvue-tabulator - Not found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  '@types/vue-tabulator@latest' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
```

[EDIT 2]

About the shims I have two related files in my `src` folder:

`shims-tsx.d.ts`:

```
import Vue, { VNode } from 'vue'

declare global {
  namespace JSX {
    // tslint:disable no-empty-interface
    interface Element extends VNode {}
    // tslint:disable no-empty-interface
    interface ElementClass extends Vue {}
    interface IntrinsicElements {
      [elem: string]: any
    }
  }
}
```

`shims-vue.d.ts`:

```
declare module '*.vue' {
  import Vue from 'vue'
  export default Vue
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First try to install @types for 'vue-tabulator' package and if it is not exist then 
you can add a shim file for type declaration for the 'vue-tabulator'

this is happening because you are using the TS for your project but 'vue-tabulator' package does not support the TS. it only has JS version of that package

how to add shims

1. inside you src folder of you project should have a folder call 'shims'
2. create a new file with name and extension like 'shims-tabulator.d.ts'
3. copy and past following code into that file 'declare module 'vue-tabulator';' (declare module 'vue-tabulator';)
4. restart your project

Comment: I updated my post with an EDIT. Long story short, installing ts types didn't work (does not exist basically).

Comment: can you try to add shims for the 'vue-tabulator' package like above example

Comment: I don't have a folder `shims` in `src` but rather two files `shims-tsx.d.ts` and `shims-vue.d.ts`.

Comment: yes. then create a new file in the same location,

later you can put those files into a folder for good practice

Comment: sure let me try this out!