# Could not find the declaration file of my Typescript library even when it exists

Tags: typescript, typescript-declarations

I have the exact same problem mentioned in this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41292559/could-not-find-a-declaration-file-for-module-module-name-path-to-module-nam), but unfortunately I was not able to solve it in the same way.

Basically I wrote a Typescript library and now, before publishing it, I would like to test it locally and check if it gets imported correctly.

This is my test project tree:

```
.
├── js-src
│   └── index.js
├── node_modules
│   └── response-giver -> ../../response-giver
├── package-lock.json
├── tsconfig.json
└── ts-src
    └── index.ts
```

You can see my module directly on my repo: https://github.com/Giovarco/response-given/tree/develop

This is how I tried to change the `tsconfig.json` on my module to solve the problem:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "emitDecoratorMetadata" : true,
        "experimentalDecorators" : true,
        "module" : "commonjs",
        "target" : "ES5",
        "watch" : true,
        "outDir" : "js-src",
        "rootDir" : "ts-src",
        "declaration": true,
        "allowJs": false,
        "lib": [ "es2015" ],
        "typeRoots": [
            "node_modules/@types",
            "js-src/index"
        ],
        "main" : "js-src/index"

    }
}
```

This is how I am trying to import my module:

```
import * as responseGiver from "response-giver";
```

but I get this error:

```
[ts]
Could not find a declaration file for module 'response-giver'. '/home/mario/Git projects/response-giver/js-src/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/response-giver` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'response-giver';`
```

This is what works nonetheless:

```
import * as responseGiver from "../node_modules/response-giver";
```

but I don't get the right signature for my functions when I try to use them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved the problem. Basically add `"types": "js-src/index.d.ts"` to the `package.json`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have node_modules/@types/response-giver ?

Comment: No, I don't. But, as you can see on my repo, I have `index.d.ts` under `/home/mario/Git projects/response-giver/js-src/`

Comment: Try adding index.d.ts in @types/response-giver .

Comment: I did not actually try your approach, but I found a solution. I will post it as a different answer. Thanks anyway