# unexpected identifier in .d.ts file

Tags: javascript, typescript, type-definition, declaration-files

I am using typescript with the following build instructions.

```
"build:types": "tsc --emitDeclarationOnly",
"build:js": "babel src --out-dir lib --extensions \".ts,.tsx\" --source-maps inline",
"start": "npm run build:types && npm run build:js && node ./lib/bin/www.js"
```

One of my `.ts` files imports mongoose. When running `npm start` I get the following error. in the `.d.ts` file

```
\lib\models\v1\collection1.model.d.ts:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import mongoose from 'mongoose';
                                                                     ^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

note "@types/mongoose" and "mongoose" are dependence already.

the content of collection1.model.d.ts is as follows. which is generated by `tsc --emitDeclarationOnly`

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
declare const _default: mongoose.Model<mongoose.Document, {}>;
export default _default;
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
  "target": "es2015",                       
  "module": "commonjs",                     
  "declaration": true,                     
  "outDir": "./lib",                          
  "strict": false,                           
  "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,     
  "esModuleInterop": true,
},
"include": ["src"]
```

}

.babelrc

```
{
"presets": [
    "@babel/env",
    "@babel/typescript"
],
"plugins": [
    "@babel/proposal-class-properties",
    "@babel/proposal-object-rest-spread",
    "@babel/transform-runtime"
]
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mongoose Import for TypeScript Doesn't Work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49001632/mongoose-import-for-typescript-doesnt-work)

Comment: @Matt Thanks but that did not work.

Comment: A `.d.ts` file shouldn't have functions in it.  This is a little confusing.  Is `collection1.model.d.ts` your file?

Comment: @Pace i added the content of the .d.ts file

Comment: Ok. What is your target set to in tsconfig.json? How are you running it, with NodeJS?  Which version.  It looks like your compiled JS includes `import` which usually only happens if targetting ES6 or above but `NodeJS` doesn't have support for `import` yet.

Comment: @Pace added tsconfig.json code. I run it using npm start

Comment: @Pace note that the .d.ts file is generated with the tsc --emitDeclarationOnly command

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is I should have not used babel and instead simply use tsc to generate all the code. Thank you to all that helped