# TypeError: mongoose__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_15___default.a.connect is not a function

Tags: typescript, mongoose

Hello I am getting the error `TypeError: mongoose__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_15___default.a.connect is not a function`

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
const dbURI = 'myurlstuffhere';
mongoose.connect(dbURI , {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true}); //fails here
```

I also used
npm install mongoose --save
to install the package

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mongoose Import for TypeScript Doesn't Work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49001632/mongoose-import-for-typescript-doesnt-work)

Comment: I tried doing "esModuleInterop":true and npm install mongoose @types/mongoose --save but it did not change anything

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Nextjs then specify "use server" in that file