# Attempting to use country-data-list js lib in typescript

Tags: typescript, .d.ts

I'm attempting to make use of [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/country-data-list) lib in typescript.

Example:

```
import { countries } from 'country-data-list';

class TestClass {

  test(): void {
    console.log(countries.all);
  }

}
```

First of all I'm getting the problem that there is no d.ts file for the project so I'm getting an error on line 1

> "Could not find declaration file for module 'country-data-list'."

in order to mitigate this I define a file '**country-data-list.d.ts**' with the following content:

```
declare module 'country-data-list' {

  const countries: any;

  export {
    countries
  };

}
```

This fixes the declaration error but countries ref. is undefined in my code. Any suggestions as to why this does not work?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41292559/could-not-find-a-declaration-file-for-module-module-name-path-to-module-nam

Comment: Hi Fazie. As explained in the above I have solved the problem of typescript not being able to find the declaration file. Now I'm only facing an undefined ref. in my code when accessing "countries". I.e. console.log(countries.all) prints out undefined. I can not see any solution to this problem in the post you referenced?