# How can I import third party package without d.ts file?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vue-cli-3

I'm studying typescript. I get some errors when I tried import some packages. I was check in `node_modules` folder, it downloaded but this don't have a `*.d.ts` file. How can I import them?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not find a declaration file for module 'module-name'. '/path/to/module-name.js' implicitly has an 'any' type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41292559/could-not-find-a-declaration-file-for-module-module-name-path-to-module-nam)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put all your custom imports in my own file. For instance, create shared/types/imports.d.ts file.

```
declare module "vue-multiselect";
declare module "vue-notification";
```

And in your tsconfig.json file include those imports with the following lines.

```
"typeRoots": [
  "node_modules/@types", "VueApp/shared/types"
],
```

And of course, restart your IDE because sometimes it doesn't detect the change immediately.

Comment: Sure, no problem. Good luck with further development.

Answer (score 2):

Make modules for them. Make sure to include the path to your `types` directory locally:

```
declare module 'vue-cookie' {

}
```

All `module declarations` need to be in their own, separate files. For instance, the vue-cookie file should be named something to the effect of `vue-cookie.d.ts`.

Also, as you go through the module, you can start typing it correctly.