# React Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-vis'

Tags: reactjs, react-tsx, react-vis

I installed react-vis library for my react code.
I used this command, like in the tutorial: `npm install react-vis --save`
But when I include the library with this code: `import {XYPlot, XAxis, YAxis, HorizontalGridLines, LineSeries} from 'react-vis';` 
It gives me the following error:

`Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-vis'. 'C:/react-vis/dist/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.`
`Try npm install @types/react-vis if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing declare module 'react-vis';`
And even that doesn't work.
Anyone know how to do this?
I'm just a beginner in react.

Answer (score 4):

A declaration file was created by evgsil; you can get the declaration file he created in his repo at https://github.com/evgsil/react-vis-typings.  It is the react-vis.d.ts file.  To use it, you can copy the file to a local folder and then reference it from the file that imports react-vis.  To reference it, you may add

```
/// <reference path="./react-vis.d.ts"/>
```

to the top of the file that imports it.  The value assigned to the reference path should be the relative path to wherever you saved the d.ts file.

So a file with react-vis imported may look like this:

```js
/// <reference path="../../../dts/react-vis.d.ts"/>
import React from 'react';
import "react-vis/dist/style.css";
import {XYPlot, XAxis, YAxis, HorizontalGridLines, LineSeries} from 'react-vis';

export function FirstPlot() {
    return(
        <XYPlot
            width={300}
            height={300}>
            <HorizontalGridLines />
            <LineSeries
                data={[
                {x: 1, y: 10},
                {x: 2, y: 5},
                {x: 3, y: 15}
                ]}/>
        <XAxis />
            <YAxis />
        </XYPlot>
    )
}
```

Hopefully an @types solution will be forthcoming soon, but until then this has worked for me.

P.S.  If you are wondering what that `/// <reference path />` is all about, you can read the specific documentation about it [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html).  In typescript, it is called a "triple-slash directive."

Comment: I didn't need the `///` reference.  The project automagically found it.

Answer (score 1):

I created a demo in this sandbox here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/64k21qmq43

make sure you have the latest version of react-vis (1.11.2)

**Package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
    "react-vis": "1.11.2"
  },
```

Maybe remove all your node modules and run npm install again with your new updated package.json.
Usually the error you describe come with your modules acting weird... So thats why i suggest to re-install them ;)

then your component will work fine like this:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import {
  XYPlot,
  XAxis,
  YAxis,
  HorizontalGridLines,
  LineSeries
} from "react-vis";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <XYPlot width={300} height={300}>
        <HorizontalGridLines />
        <LineSeries data={[{ x: 1, y: 10 }, { x: 2, y: 5 }, { x: 3, y: 15 }]} />
        <XAxis />
        <YAxis />
      </XYPlot>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

If you follow my sandbox example you should be fine!, good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are using typescript for compiling your code.
First try 
`npm install @types/react-vis`.
If it does not work then you have to take longer route:
- Create a folder name : **typings** in the root of your project,
- inside typings create a new folder with name: "**react-vis"** and in that folder create a **react-vis.d.ts** file
- write `declare module 'react-vis'` in react-vis.d.ts file.

```
// react-vis.d.ts
 declare module 'react-vis';</br>
```

- go to your **tsconfig.json** file and add `"typeRoots": [ "../../typings", "../../node_modules/@types"]` in the compilerOptions (with the proper relative path to your folders) to let TypeScript know where it can find the types definitions of your libraries and modules and add a new property
- add `exclude": ["../../node_modules", "../../typings"]` " to the tsconfig.json file.
Here is an example of how your tsconfig.json file should look like:

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "../dst/",
    "target": "ESNEXT",
    "typeRoots": [
        "../../typings",
        "../../node_modules/@types"
    ]
},
"lib": [
        "es2016"
],
"exclude": [
    "../../node_modules",
    "../../typings"
]
```

}
For more information, do refer to : https://stackoverflow.com/a/51320328/4998546

Comment: Ill give it a try

Comment: I guess "npm start"  should work fine, if you have typescript script settings already done...

Comment: you should run the project like you normally do.. Like : "npm run start" may be.

Comment: Then ill get `missing script start`

Comment: Can you please tell, when are you getting this error "Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-vis'.".
And I am assuming you have a react project created with package.json files and all.

Comment: Yes, im getiing the error at the home page, and Im working on a existing project with typescript and react

Comment: The home page is also the page where the charts needs to appear

Comment: can you please check your projects package.json file and check for the "scripts" in that file??

Comment: Im using dotnet run