# Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-native-foo-package'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, node-modules

while I added any component to my pure react-native project, the application screen turns to the white empty page.
The import 'react-native-foo-package' line has '...' near the package name, and it has this message:

> [ts]
>   not find a declaration file for module 'react-native-foo-package'. '/project/node_modules/'react-native-foo-package'/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
>   Try npm install @types/'react-native-foo-package' if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'react-native-foo-package';`

npm install @types/'react-native-foo-package' couldn't help, because this package doesn't exist in npm.
I don't use any typescript file or related code to typescript.

react: "16.6.0-alpha.8af6728"

react-native: "0.57.4"

- This question [Could not find a declaration file for module 'module-name'. '/path/to/module-name.js' implicitly has an 'any' type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41292559/could-not-find-a-declaration-file-for-module-module-name-path-to-module-nam) doesn't answer my question, because, in my package.json file, there is no "main" exists.

Comment: This question has all the solutions you need https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41292559/could-not-find-a-declaration-file-for-module-module-name-path-to-module-nam

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not find a declaration file for module 'module-name'. '/path/to/module-name.js' implicitly has an 'any' type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41292559/could-not-find-a-declaration-file-for-module-module-name-path-to-module-nam)

Comment: @Think-Twice I edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well @Samane Yaghoobi is right! it has nothing to do with "main":"index.js".
Here's what you should do. After successfully setting up the library in your project on whatever platform (VsCode or Atom). Re run the project from the command line => react-native run-android. After that, navigate to your project in Android Studio. Then open up build.gradle and sync your gradle again. Then just to make sure, checkout the MainApplication in Android Studio to see if the file(e.g. import com.whatever.foo) imported properly, if everything looks good, you are good to go. If you need further instructions in setting up the library in VsCode/Atom let me know, I will create visual presentation to make things much more clear.