# how do I npm install node-gmail-api?

Tags: node.js, typescript, gmail-api

After I did npm install node-gmail-api, my code cannot find the model. It said "Could not find a declaration file for module 'node-gmail-api'. '/Users/xuanren/Desktop/test/node_modules/node-gmail-api/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/node-gmail-api` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'node-gmail-api';` [7016]"

I checked my node_modules folder, node-gmail-api is there. How do i install node-gmail-api properly?

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41292559/could-not-find-a-declaration-file-for-module-module-name-path-to-module-nam), try to install its from `@types`: `npm install -D @types/module-name`.

> Or, if install error, try rewrite `import` to `require`:
>
> ```
> // import * as yourModuleName from 'module-name';
> const yourModuleName = require('module-name');
> ```

Also, if you're importing a third-party module example 'foo' that doesn't provide any typings, either in the library itself, or in the `@types/foo` package, then you can make this error go away by declaring the module in a `.d.ts` file:

> ```
> // foo.d.ts
> declare module 'foo';
> ```
>
> Then when you import foo it'll just be typed as any.

Comment: emmmm it is not working.  this is what i got from terminal "code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: @types/node-gmail-api@latest"