# Could not find a declaration file for module 'nexmo'

Tags: javascript, react-native, vonage

I would like to have my sms api called nexmo but when i installed this happend

```
[ts]
Could not find a declaration file for module 'nexmo'. 'c:/Users/User/IPROCESS FOLDER/Iprocess/node_modules/nexmo/lib/Nexmo.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Try `npm install @types/nexmo` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'nexmo';` [7016]'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not find a declaration file for module 'module-name'. '/path/to/module-name.js' implicitly has an 'any' type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41292559/could-not-find-a-declaration-file-for-module-module-name-path-to-module-nam)