# Feathersjs, feathersjs-vuex clean npm install giving issue

Tags: feathersjs, feathers-sequelize, feathers-vuex

I am setting up a new web app with feathersjs as the back end and Vue + feathers client (feathers-vuex) as my front end. However, after installing the packages using npm, I am getting multiple import errors as follows -

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'module-name'. '/path/to/module-name.js' implicitly has an 'any' type
```

This is happening for the following modules (including npm install command):

Frontend:

```
    @feathersjs/feathers 
    @feathersjs/socketio-client 
    socket.io-client 
    @feathersjs/authentication-client 
    feathers-vuex --save
```

Backend:

```
    feathers-sequelize
    feathersjs-authentication
    feathersjs-authentication-local
```

I looked at this stackoverflow question 
[Could not find a declaration file for module 'module-name'. '/path/to/module-name.js' implicitly has an 'any' type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41292559/could-not-find-a-declaration-file-for-module-module-name-path-to-module-nam)

I  tried to install types from @types which worked for some of the modules except for: feathers-sequelize (Backend) and feathers-vuex (Frontend)

It seems *.d.ts file is not created for either and that is what is missing from my current setup.

Is there something basic that I am missing? I am new to the world of node.js and feathersjs so apologies for any noob mistakes!