# Error using ES Module import for object-set-all-values-to

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-typings, object-set-all-values-to

In an Angular 6 project I'm trying to use the npm package [object-set-all-values-to](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-set-all-values-to) `3.9.45`. I did the following:

1- Installed it using `npm i object-set-all-values-to` ✔️ OK

2- Tried to import it ❌ Error

- 1st option

`import setAllValuesTo from 'object-set-all-values-to';`

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'object-set-all-values-to'. '<my-project-path>/node_modules/object-set-all-values-to/dist/object-set-all-values-to.cjs.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/object-set-all-values-to` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'object-set-all-values-to';`
```

- 2nd option:

`import setAllValuesTo from 'object-set-all-values-to/dist/object-set-all-values-to.esm.js';`

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'object-set-all-values-to'. '<my-project-path>/node_modules/object-set-all-values-to/dist/object-set-all-values-to.esm.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/object-set-all-values-to` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'object-set-all-values-to/dist/object-set-all-values-to.esm.js';`
```

**So, How can I solve this issue**❔

---

This alternative (`const setAllValuesTo = require('object-set-all-values-to');`) works but I cannot use it because of strict code-styles rules in my project.

---

I already tried without success what is proposed to solve similar issues in:

- [Could not find a declaration file for module 'module-name'. '/path/to/module-name.js' implicitly has an 'any' type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41292559/could-not-find-a-declaration-file-for-module-module-name-path-to-module-nam)

For example, put above the import line `// @ts-ignore` and also to declare in a `src/typings.d.ts` file the module:

```
declare module 'object-set-all-values-to' {
    export default function setAllValuesTo(inputOriginal: any, valueOriginal: any): any
}
```

These give me the following error: `object_set_all_values_to_1.default is not a function`.

Also, I tried `npm install @types/object-set-all-values-to` but it seems there is not *types* defined for it because I get `npm ERR! code E404`.

---

Some possibly relevant config values in `tsconfig.json` are:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        // ...
        "lib": [
            "dom",
            "es2018.promise",
            "es2015"
        ],
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es5",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        // ...
    }
}
```

I tried changing `noImplicitAny` to `false` and the error reported is gone but the I get the mentioned `object_set_all_values_to_1.default is not a function`

---

I reported already the [issue](https://gitlab.com/codsen/codsen/issues/19) to the package author but got no answer so far.

Comment: Works fine for me in Angular 6.1.10 without any additional changes: https://i.imgur.com/xnKW73A.png. What do your tsconfig.json and tsconfig.app.json files look like? What's your exact Angular version?

Comment: @Gosha_Fighten interesting! Got to check the whole config, I'm trying to use it in a HUGE project.

Comment: @Gosha_Fighten The Angular version is `6.1.10`. Should I look for any specific config inside `tsconfig.json` and `tsconfig.app.json`?

Comment: First, I'd check what value the `compilerOptions.module` option has in tsconfigs.

Comment: where did ou create your typings.d.ts file with the declaration??

Comment: @Gosha_Fighten `compilerOptions.module` is `commonjs` ... updated the post.

Comment: @FRECIA `typings.d.ts` is inside `src` (`<project-root>/src/typings.d.ts`). I updated the post... I don't think the place of `typings.d.ts` is the problem. Do yo have anything in mind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `compilerOptions.module` is `commonjs`, an UMD module is used. In this case, import this library as

```
import * as setAllValuesTo from 'object-set-all-values-to';
```

Comment: You were right about the import syntax. This solved the error `object_set_all_values_to_1.default is not a function`. Additionally I had to use the `// @ts-ignore` to suppress the compiler error because I cannot change the `tsconfig.json`

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your config, I believe the issue is with the module definition config being set to commonjs, change it to `esnext`:

```
"module": "esnext"
```

Comment: Nope... didn't work.... this is driving me nuts.... actually I created a sample Angular project from scratch to trys this npm package independently and it works out of the box. There must be some misconfiguration in this huge project I'm working on :( Thank you very much for the effort

Comment: That's too bad. Pleas post the fix when you find it, I'm really intrigued now.

Comment: [Gosha_Fighten's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58395908/error-using-es-module-import-for-object-set-all-values-to/58397541#58397541) solved it. In any case your help was very useful too. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should have to import the object_set_all_values_to_1.default. It's not a function as you declare it.

```
import * as setAllValuesTo from 'object-set-all-values-to';
```

Comment: Hi, smita. The answer from Gosha_Fighten pointed this out already. Thanks for posting.