# TypeScript error importing vue package (vue-cli3 proj)

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, webpack, vue-cli-3

I have a project with newest dependencies set up wizth CLI 3. I get error when importing [font-picker-vue](https://www.npmjs.com/package/font-picker-vue) package in my project (package installs successfully though).

The error: `Could not find a declaration file for module 'font-picker-vue'......../node_modules/font-picker-vue/lib/FontPicker.js' implicitly has an 'any' type. 
Try npm install @types/font-picker-vue if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing declare module font-picker-vue';`

Did a google search and one of the solution suggested was to add following code in a `*.d.ts` file:
[src](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/5944#issuecomment-535683821)

```
declare module 'vuetify/lib' {
  import 'vuetify/types/lib'
}
```

Created a `*.d.ts` file in the root of the proj as shown in below image, hoping that it would work, but it did not:

[image: *.d.ts file in project directory]

Next, as suggested [SO reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42505940/8069961) changed import statements to require: `const yourModuleName = require('module-name');` and also tried installing from `npm install -D @types/font-picker-vue`. Both didn't work, @types/font-picker-vue isn't in the npm registry.

I am not sure how to resolve this error. Can somebody help be get this working. Any help is apprecited. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Create a yourModuleName.d.ts file with the module declaration like this `declare module 'vuetify/lib'` then try adding this:

```
"include": "*.d.ts"
```

To your tsconfig.json file