# React error importing JS file without type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to use a 'scroll to top' component:

`import ScrollUpButton from 'react-scroll-up-button';`

It seems that because I am using Typescript, it doesn't accept this import for some reason. I get an unusual error, but no idea what to do with it (the first recommendation for Typing does not work):

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-scroll-up-button'. '/../react-scroll-up-button/dist/react-scroll-up-button.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/react-scroll-up-button` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'react-scroll-up-button';`
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41292559/could-not-find-a-declaration-file-for-module-module-name-path-to-module-nam

Comment: Changing from import to require generates a completely different type of error with the core (albeit, no longer with this library): Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a typedef file(`react-scroll-up-button.d.ts`) inside the folder where you have your `.ts` file with the next content:

```
declare module 'foo';
```

This will create a basic type definition, so your `ScrollUpButton` will be of type `any`. You could extend the type def if you want, but this should be enough to clean up the error.