# Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-tilt'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, import, typescript-typings

I installed and imported react-tilt following this [page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-tilt), but got below message and unable to use it. I am not sure what the message suggest. Does somebody know how to fix it?
[image]

Comment: You imported a JavaScript file into a TypeScript file and the TypeScript compiler is telling you it has no idea what the types are for that JavaScript file.

Comment: Why isn't there issue for other modules but Tilt?

Comment: Because the other modules export a declaration file along with their JavaScript. `react-tilt` is not a TypeScript module.

Comment: Thanks, any suggestions to fix it?

Comment: "add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'react-tilt';`". The directions are pretty clear.

Comment: Thanks you very much!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not find a declaration file for module 'module-name'. '/path/to/module-name.js' implicitly has an 'any' type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41292559/could-not-find-a-declaration-file-for-module-module-name-path-to-module-nam)

Answer (score 0):

**VS Code tell you to add manually the declaration for this module.**

You can do it by creating a new file called `index.d.ts` inside the module (`/node_modules/react-tilt`)
and add the following line inside it :

```js
declare module 'react-tilt';
```

A way to do it faster, just copy paste the following line in your terminal.

> If you're using bash or zsh :

```bash
cd ./node_modules/react-tilt && touch index.d.ts && echo "declare module 'react-tilt';" > index.d.ts
```

> If you're using windows terminal :

```
cd ./node_modules/react-tilt && echo declare module 'react-tilt'; > index.d.ts
```