# Moment Timezone in Angular 9

Tags: angular9, moment-timezone, angular10

Currently, I upgrade my Angular project form `8` to `9`. 
The project's using a `"@types/moment-timezone": "^0.5.30"` in `package.json` 
Now this package has been deprecated. https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/moment-timezone

When I run the project `ng serve`, it shows up this error message

```
user.model.ts:3:25 - error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'moment-timezone'. '/home/bunthai/sftp/upgrade/projectg/ui/ctr/node_modules/moment-timezone/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/moment-timezone` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'moment-timezone';`

import * as moment from 'moment-timezone';
                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

How to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42505940/10258377

In my case change from `import * as moment from 'moment-timezone'` to `const moment = require('moment-timezone');`

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove this import, and import your wanted timezone manualy eg:

```
import moment from "moment";
import "moment/locale/fr";
moment.locale('fr')
```

If you don't import another timezone, you'll get the default nodeJS server timezone. If you want another, you need to import it and use it.

Just and advice, [stop using this library if you can](https://inventi.studio/en/blog/why-you-shouldnt-use-moment-js).

Comment: What do you mean "your wanted timezone"? Another timezone library?