# Not requiring a module, but getting: Could not find a declaration file for module 'module-name'. '/path/module-name.js' implicitly has an 'any' type

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm getting the following errors: `Could not find a declaration file for module 'module-name'. '/path/to/module-name.js' implicitly has an 'any' type`, and I know exactly what to do in those cases (see solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41292559/could-not-find-a-declaration-file-for-module-module-name-path-to-module-nam) for example).

But the problem is, those are NPM modules, that I'm not using directly!
For example, I added `mongodb` to my `package.json` file, and it requires `bluebird`, but I'm not requiring `bluebird` myself.

Still, I get that error. But I don't want to run `npm install @types/bluebird`, which will stay there forever, even if `mongodb` will stop requiring `bluebird`.

Isn't there a way to suppress those errors for modules not required by me?