# Importing external library - could not find declaration file - Vue 3 and Typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

Im trying to import my external library with Vue 3 and Typescript

Typescript says it can't find the declaration file in my library index.js, but since i use this library for different projects (Vue 2 and projects without Typescript) I dont really want to change it all that much.

Is there any way to let Typescript ignore this index.js or should I start refactoring my Library to Typescript?

```
import {
    MyText,
} from '@myapp/vue-components';

export const registerComponents = (app: App): void => {
    app.component(MyText)
}
```

Comment: Have made the library compatible with Vue 3?

Comment: Yes - do you think the problem comes from Vue2 -> Vue3 and not Typescript trying to read index.js?

I know i should refactor to Vue3

Comment: I don't have much experience with TS so I couldn't say. Do you import all your components into an index.js?

Comment: Yes - it looks in the index.js -> export default -> Vue.component(MyText). Im going to refactor the files now, checking if that'll do the job. Thanks

Comment: @EliasMarcoLip For your own non-TypeScript custom lib, I would just [declare the module in a `.d.ts` file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50516783/6277151).