# Invalid module name in augmentation - not able to resolve for progress-bar-webpack-plugin

Tags: typescript, webpack, type-declaration

**webpack.config.dev.ts**

```
import * as ProgressBarPlugin from 'progress-bar-webpack-plugin';
```

> Error: Could not find a declaration file for module 'progress-bar-webpack-plugin'

If I try to add a module in a declaration file:

**index.d.ts**

```
declare module "progress-bar-webpack-plugin";
```

> Error: Invalid module name in augmentation. Module 'progress-bar-webpack-plugin' resolves to an untyped module at '.../myproject/node_modules/progress-bar-webpack-plugin/index.js', which cannot be augmented.ts(2665)

Comment: is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41292559/could-not-find-a-declaration-file-for-module-module-name-path-to-module-nam) of any help?

Answer (score 2):

Imports should be declared inside the module declaration.
Example:

```
declare module 'node-helper-lib' {
   import * as SomeThirdParty from 'node-helper-lib';
   interface Helper {
       new(opt: SomeThirdParty.Options): SomeThirdParty.Type
   }
   export = Helper;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its ok I realised i could install the @types file for this.

```
yarn add @types/progress-bar-webpack-plugin --save-dev
```