# Why is typeRoots not recommended for specifying the location of d.ts files?

Tags: typescript, node-modules, tsconfig, ts-node

In the following [SO comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41292559/could-not-find-a-declaration-file-for-module-module-name-path-to-module-nam#comment89715780_50516783), which has 19 upvotes, the user says the following with regards to Typescript declaration files and the use of `typeRoots`:

> @Tom It looks for .d.ts files in the same places that it will look for
> normal .ts files: as specified "files", "include", and "exclude" in
> the tsconfig.json. I would not recommend using typeRoots for this
> purpose: that's intended for the location of external type modules
> (i.e. node_modules/@types), not individual .d.ts files.

Essentially the user is saying that `typeRoots` should not be used for individual .d.ts files but I'm unsure as to why this is the case. **Is there a good reason for this?**

To add to my confusion, the `ts-node` module specifically recommends users to use the `typeRoots` property in `tsconfig.json` to declare global type definitions. The documentation outlining this can be found [here](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node#help-my-types-are-missing).

**So the question is, should I use `typeRoots` in the manner outlined by the `ts-node` documentation to declare global type definitions?**

Comment: Damn no answer ?