# Animated Cluster from OL-EXT library and Typescript

Tags: typescript, create-react-app, openlayers

I am using openlayer in my react web app.

Problem is I am trying to import AnimatedCluster from “ol-ext/layer/AnimatedCluster” and when I try to render using this it needs typings of ol-ext i.e. @types/ol-ext as a devDependency, which is not present in yarn packages.

How can this be resolved?

Comment: `npm install @types/ol-ext --save-dev` or `yarn install @types/ol-ext --save-dev`

Comment: As I mentioned it’s not in yarnpkg.

Comment: then you can create a declaration file yourself. Check the second answer from this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41292559/could-not-find-a-declaration-file-for-module-module-name-path-to-module-nam