# import * as html2pdf from 'html2pdf.js';

Tags: angular, jspdf, html2pdf

html2pdf.js working in some angular projects and not working in some.

I want to use html2pdf.js for adding page breaks while generating pdf.

I am declaring it like below

```
import * as html2pdf from 'html2pdf.js';
```

It is working for one project with the below package.json

```
{
  "name": "footytrivia-ui",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~9.1.6",
    "@angular/common": "~9.1.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.1.6",
    "@angular/core": "~9.1.6",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.1.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.1.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.1.6",
    "@angular/router": "~9.1.6",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^10.0.0",
    "@ngrx/schematics": "^10.0.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^10.0.0",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^10.0.0",
    "angularx-social-login": "^2.3.1",
    "angularx-social-login-ivy": "^1.2.9",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "html2canvas": "^1.1.4",
    "html2pdf.js": "^0.9.3",
    "jspdf": "^2.3.1",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^5.6.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.901.5",
    "@angular/cli": "~9.1.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.1.6",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.3",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.8.3"
  }
}
```

And not working for the below package.json

```
{
  "name": "demo-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "^12.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "*",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/material": "^12.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "~12.0.3",
    "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^18.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "^5.0.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
    "html2pdf.js": "^0.9.3",
    "jspdf": "^2.3.1",
    "ng2-charts": "^2.2.3",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^6.2.0",
    "ngx-toastr": "^14.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.1.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/cli": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.0.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.7.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "typescript": "~4.2.3"
  }
}
```

The message says

error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'html2pdf.js'.

Edit ------------

tsconfig.json for Working solution

```
    {
      "compileOnSave": false,
      "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "downlevelIteration": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "module": "esnext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "importHelpers": true,
        "target": "es2015",
        "lib": [
          "es2018",
          "dom"
        ]
      },
      "angularCompilerOptions": {
        "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
        "strictInjectionParameters": true
      }
    }
```

tsconfig.json for non working solution.

```
/* To learn more about this file see: https://angular.io/config/tsconfig. */
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ],
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
}
```

RESOLVED:

I did not import it the html2pdf.js.

```
<script src="https://rawgit.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf/master/dist/html2pdf.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

This script was already present in the index.html.

I just declared the variable in the component.

```
declare var html2pdf: any;
```

Worked for me.

Comment: Probably a problem with `tsconfig.json`

Comment: Sharing the tsconfig.json for both projects

Comment: @DVN-Anakin please have a look if you find anything, I have updated the question with tsconfig.json files

Comment: Maybe try to use the working settings of  `angularCompilerOptions` in your `tsconfig`, also maybe remove lines 6, 7, 8, 9

Comment: Nope, not working. Is there any chance that it might happen because of the Angular version?

Comment: Maybe a duplicate question with multiple solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41292559/could-not-find-a-declaration-file-for-module-module-name-path-to-module-nam