# import statement is not pointing to node_modules

Tags: node.js, typescript

i am using express with typescript.
there i am importing a module

```
import SomeModuleType from '3rd-party-module';
```

but since this didn't had type definitions available in npm

`src/app.ts:5:21 - error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module '3rd-party-module'. 'C:/Work/node_modules/3rd-party-module/dist/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type. Try 'npm i --save-dev @types/3rd-party-module' if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing 'declare module '3rd-party-module';`
`5 import SomeModuleType from "3rd-party-module";`

so used method given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51320328/11847762).
the error was gone but, but now the import was unable to find the module definitions from node_modules.

```
const logger = new SomeModuleType.ContentLogger();
```

gave error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'ContentLogger' of undefined`

i tried `Go to definition` in vsCode, but that was taking me to the custom index.d.ts file containing

```
declare module "3rd-party-module";
```

how to make this run. with proper typescript rules.

Comment: Could you specify which module you're trying to import (and which libraery it comes from)? The syntax for importing varies depending on how the module is exported.

Comment: actually its a private package of my client. so, it's unavailable publicly and also it does not have @types packages.. the main issue of confusion is, when imported in app.js file, the ctrl+click is working, but when i am importing in the app.ts file, the import doesn't work

Comment: Oh, I see. I've added a couple of possible syntaxes that could maybe do the trick in my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try importing using one of the following syntaxes:

```js
import * as SomeModuleType from '3rd-party-module';
```

```js
import SomeModuleType = require('3rd-party-module');
```

Last resort:

```js
const SomeModuleType = require('3rd-party-module');
```

Comment: import SomeModuleType = require('3rd-party-module'); This worked..