# how to import 'azure-storage' package using typecript?

Tags: typescript, azure-storage

if I import it like the following code, there is a error tip. how to solve it ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the module like this

try to install types from `@types`

```
npm install -D @types/module-name
```

If the above install errors - try changing import statements to require:

```
// import * as yourModuleName from 'module-name';
const yourModuleName = require('module-name');
```

when you are using external libraries and modules with TypeScript, they need to contain files that describe the types in that code. Those files are called type declaration files with an extension **d.ts**. Most of the declaration types for npm modules are already written and you can include them using **npm install @types/module_name** (where module_name is the name of the module whose types you want to include.

there are modules that don't have their type definitions so try to import the module using `import * as module_name from 'module-name',` create a folder **typings** in the root of your project, inside create a new folder with your module name and in that folder create a **module_name.d.ts** file and write declare module **'module_name'**. After this just go to your **tsconfig.json** file and add `"typeRoots": [ "../../typings", "../../node_modules/@types"]` in the compiler Options (with the proper relative path to your folders) to let TypeScript know where it can find the types definitions of your libraries and modules and add a new property

```
"exclude": ["../../node_modules", "../../typings"]
```

Please check this for reference and other possible options [Could not find a declaration file for module 'module-name'. '/path/to/module-name.js' implicitly has an 'any' type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41292559/could-not-find-a-declaration-file-for-module-module-name-path-to-module-nam)