# React: npm i {any package} is not creating declaration files

Tags: reactjs, npm

I'm new to React (and really web development) and I'm working in one of the starter projects.  I have tried to install several npm packages to work with and they seem to be installing correctly.  I can import the class into my Main.js file but when I hover over the import it says

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-ui-cards'. '.../Gatsby/node_modules/react-ui-cards/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

and it will throw an error if I try to build using these components

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not find a declaration file for module 'module-name'. '/path/to/module-name.js' implicitly has an 'any' type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41292559/could-not-find-a-declaration-file-for-module-module-name-path-to-module-nam)

Comment: No this did not help.  I tried 'const ProductCard = require('react-ui-cards');' and I get the same error.  I also tried creating my own .d.ts file and that didn't work either

Comment: Now I'm getting 'window is not defined'