# How to resolve TypeScript declaration file error with observablehq/plot

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, next.js, observablehq

I am using react and Next.js, I am following this guide https://github.com/observablehq/plot with the goal to render/visualize some data from a heroku postgres DB. I used npm install @observablehq/plot.

`import * as Plot from '@observablehq/plot'`

This import line is raising a ts7016 error:

```
Could not find a declaration file for module '@observablehq/plot'. '/Users/alejandrozapien/bexar-dash/node_modules/@observablehq/plot/src/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm i --save-dev @types/observablehq__plot` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module '@observablehq/plot';
```

I am new to learning Typescript and creating declaration files. How should I go about resolving this error properly? I read I should create a global.d.ts file but I am unsure of where to place that file or how to structure it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not find a declaration file for module 'module-name'. '/path/to/module-name.js' implicitly has an 'any' type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41292559/could-not-find-a-declaration-file-for-module-module-name-path-to-module-nam)

Comment: It helped thank you, I created a single file in the project root named observablehq.d.ts and it has a single ‘declare module’ statement. That resolved the issue, however I feel it’s a bit excessive to create its own file. My question is where should I put a single file fire statements like this in my project tree?

Comment: I wouldn't say it's excessive if it helps you remember why you did that, looking back after you've forgot.

Comment: Plot now exports declaration files, as of v0.6.5, released April 1. https://github.com/observablehq/plot/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#065