# node_modules/@types/chrome/index.d.ts is not a module

Tags: reactjs, typescript, google-chrome, nrwl-nx

I've nx monorepo having React TypeScript app.
When I'm trying to use `chrome` in any of `.ts` file, VSCode is reporting a error saying `Cannot find name 'chrome'.`

I've used `yarn add @types/chrome` and able to see an entry in `package.json` as `"@types/chrome": "^0.0.171",` also added below configurations to `ts.config.json` and `tsconfig.base.json`

```
    "types": [
      "chrome","@types/chrome"
    ]
```

When I tried to import `chrome` as `import chrome '@types/chrome'` or `import chrome 'chrome'` VS Code giving error as `node_modules/@types/chrome/index.d.ts' is not a module.`

Any help would be very grateful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not find a declaration file for module 'module-name'. '/path/to/module-name.js' implicitly has an 'any' type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41292559/could-not-find-a-declaration-file-for-module-module-name-path-to-module-nam)

Comment: @MohammadHosseinDolatabadi Tried the answers, but it didn't help

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a little bit old. I hope this will help someone.

If you are sure about all dependencies are installed, make a hard restart vscode.

> You can use `ctrl+shift+p` and type `reload` and enter
> `Developer:reload`

Answer (score 1):

Using just `import 'chrome';` instead of `import { chrome } from 'chrome';` worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I tried `import 'chrome'` which works but unfortunately you won't be able to compile the TS since it's not an actual module. `Error: Cannot find module 'chrome'`

It turns out you can just reference the `chrome` namespace for types directly without importing in TS files like

```
const manifest: chrome.runtime.ManifestV3 = {
    manifest_version: 3,
    ...
}
```

or call a function like

```
  chrome.storage.local.get(["key"]).then((result) => {
    console.log("Value is " + result.key);
  });
```