# How can I convert a number into Persian words in Angular or Typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to convert numbers to words in my Angular project like this:

```
1372 --> یک هزار و سیصد و هفتاد و دو
```

I found a package called [persianJS](https://github.com/usablica/persian.js) that supports this conversion but it can't be imported in **TypeScript**, I tried:

```
import * as persianjs from 'persianjs';
```

But error says:

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'persianjs'. 'd:/Dev/front-end/Dis-dashboard/node_modules/persianjs/persian.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm i --save-dev @types/persianjs` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'persianjs';`
```

But there's no **@types/persianjs**.

Is there any package or function that can be used in Angular?

Comment: Have you tried [persian-tools](https://github.com/persian-tools/persian-tools)?

Comment: well you can make your own @types/persianjs only for what you need

Comment: @AmRzA I thinking about that.

Comment: @AdrianKokot your comment solved my problem thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of **persianJS** I used [**persian-tools**](https://github.com/persian-tools/persian-tools). first I installed with the command below:

```
npm install --save @persian-tools/persian-tools
```

Then I imported this package to my target file:

```
import * as persianTools from '@persian-tools/persian-tools';
```

And used it like this:

```
persianTools.numberToWords("123200") // returns "صد و بیست و سه هزار و دویست"
```

Comment: This is a solution to the original question the same way that buying a new car inflates your tires. You'll run into this again, here's a bunch of answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41292559/could-not-find-a-declaration-file-for-module-module-name-path-to-module-nam

Answer (score 1):

Ignore the warning by putting // @ts-ignore above your import. It's either that or create the type declaration files yourself.

Comment: Can you add more explanation to your answer?

Comment: Yes, you have your typescript configured to throw an error if it can't find type declarations of a package. So to resolve it you can either, 1. use a different package where the authors included type definitions, 2. change your typescript config so it doesn't care about that, 3. write the type definitions yourself, or 4. just tell typescript to ignore the warning.