# How to connect nestjs with 3d party JS package?

Tags: nestjs

I have find lots of solutions about nestjs with 3d party package with TS support.

But in my case, my 3d party package **doesn't support TS**.
Can somebody describe steps to connect with [openweather-apis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/openweather-apis) with a nestjs way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the 3rd-party package doesn't need to support TS in order to use it. Just install the packag as a dependency and import it as usual, just like any other nodejs project.
You could write a NestJS module to wrap the functionality of that package (like [this one](https://github.com/benhason1/nestjs-http-promise)) but it's up to you.

(assuming that your package doesn't have types on `@types/` scope) Due to the lacking of typings, you'll receive the following typescript error:

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'module-name'
```

to circumvent this, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50516783/5290447