# React: How to figure out import path of node modules

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

#### Environment

I'm using Typescript with react.

I've installed [react-bootstrap-date-picker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-bootstrap-date-picker) with `yarn install react-bootstrap-date-picker`.

The website does not tell how to import the component.

#### Question

From looking at the installed node module (within the `node_modules` folder), how do I figure out the import path of the component?

#### What I've tried

**I tried** `import { DatePicker as BSDatePicker } from 'react-bootstrap-date-picker';`, but it errors out `Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-bootstrap-date-picker'.`

Comment: did you try '@types/react-bootstrap-date-picker' instead?

Comment: this might help too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41292559/could-not-find-a-declaration-file-for-module-module-name-path-to-module-nam

Answer (score 0):

Try `default` import:

```js
import DatePicker from 'react-bootstrap-date-picker';
```

Comment: This solves the example problem, but doesn't answer the question.

Comment: I hope this article will help you [checkt](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/requiring-modules-in-node-js-everything-you-need-to-know-e7fbd119be8/)

Answer (score 0):

You are using curly braces which is not required. Try this

```
import DatePicker as BSDatePicker from 'react-bootstrap-date-picker';
```

Curly braces are used for normal imports (imports which are not default imports) while if we import something without curly braces, it means that it is default import.

Hope that this link will help you to understand further.

https://mindsers.blog/post/javascript-named-imports-vs-default-imports/

Comment: This solves the example problem, but doesn't answer the question.