# Could not find a declaration file for module 'clarifai'

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, clarifai

[image]

i have started facing this issue after i installed clarifai API for project face recognition and i tried everything but can't find the solution. It shows this message when hovering on import clarifai:

> Could not find a declaration file for module 'clarifai'

tried reinstalling clarifai and also node modules still didn't solve this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not find a declaration file for module 'module-name'. '/path/to/module-name.js' implicitly has an 'any' type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41292559/could-not-find-a-declaration-file-for-module-module-name-path-to-module-nam)

Answer (score 0):

A declaration file is only used in `TypeScript` projects. As your project is just plain `JavaScript` you can just ignore this error.

Also, Ive looked at the [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clarifai) and its neither written in `TypeScript` or has a package which provides types, eg *@types/clarifai*

So you can just ignore this error and move on with your project. This error is only gonna be an issue for `TypeScript` projects.

Answer (score 0):

Since your project is just plain JavaScript, you need to use HTTP to call the Clarifai API. You can refer to the JavaScript (REST) samples on the Clarifai documentation on how to call the face recognition API.