# clarifai FACE_DETECT_MODEL deprecated in javascript?

Tags: clarifai

Could not find a declaration file for module 'clarifai'. 'd:/jagan projects/face-detection/node_modules/clarifai/dist/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Try `npm i --save-dev @types/clarifai` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'clarifai';`ts(7016)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHow3.png)

I'm trying to connect to the API but can't execute Webpack and also can't find the solution, and the solutions are made form 2020. Can anyone answer this?

Comment: I believe your question for the issue with Clarifai has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74295005/could-not-find-a-declaration-file-for-module-clarifai/74295117#74295117
For the process is not defined error, check out this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30239060/uncaught-referenceerror-process-is-not-defined