# AWS CDK Not Finding Custom .d.ts files in project on Synth

Tags: aws-cdk, aws-cdk-typescript

I have a TypeScript CDK Project. Per the recommendation I read somewhere, I've put both my infrastructure and runtime code into the same project.

The runtime code is required to use an obscure js library which does not have any type definitions. I've created a custom .d.ts file with types as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50516783/494635). The TypeScript compiler is happy with this and `tsc` builds correctly.

When however I run `cdk synth` I get the `"Could not find a declaration file for module 'xyz'"` error. I'm guessing that the CDK can't find the definition file, however it's in the same location  as other .ts files.

I've edited `cdk.json` and removed `"**/*.d.ts"` from the exclude filter to no effect.

`tsconfig.json`:

```json
    {
      "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES2020",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "lib": [
          "es2020"
        ],
        "declaration": true,
        "strict": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "noImplicitThis": true,
        "alwaysStrict": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": false,
        "noUnusedParameters": false,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false,
        "inlineSources": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
        "typeRoots": [
          "./types",
          "./node_modules/@types"
        ],
        "outDir": "./out",                                   
        "esModuleInterop": true,                             
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,            
        "sourceMap": true,                                
      },
      "include":[
        "lib",
        "bin",
        "lib/**/*",
        "bin/**/*",
        "types"
      ],
      "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "cdk.out",
        "./out/**/*",
        "test/**/*.spec.ts"
      ]
    }
```

`cdk.json`:

```json
    {
      "app": "npx ts-node --prefer-ts-exts bin/LeopardGeotabApp.ts",
      "watch": {
        "include": [
          "**",
          "lib/geotab/mg-api.js.d.ts"
        ],
        "exclude": [
          "README.md",
          "cdk*.json",
          "**/*.d.ts",
          "**/*.js",
          "tsconfig.json",
          "package*.json",
          "yarn.lock",
          "node_modules",
          "test"
        ]
      },
      "build": "",
      "versionReporting": true,
      "context": {
        "@aws-cdk/aws-lambda:recognizeLayerVersion": true,
        "@aws-cdk/core:checkSecretUsage": true,
        "@aws-cdk/core:target-partitions": [
          "aws",
          "aws-cn"
        ],
        "@aws-cdk-containers/ecs-service-extensions:enableDefaultLogDriver": true,
        "@aws-cdk/aws-ec2:uniqueImdsv2TemplateName": true,
        "@aws-cdk/aws-ecs:arnFormatIncludesClusterName": true,
        "@aws-cdk/aws-iam:minimizePolicies": true,
        "@aws-cdk/core:validateSnapshotRemovalPolicy": true,
        "@aws-cdk/aws-codepipeline:crossAccountKeyAliasStackSafeResourceName": true,
        "@aws-cdk/aws-s3:createDefaultLoggingPolicy": true,
        "@aws-cdk/aws-sns-subscriptions:restrictSqsDescryption": true,
        "@aws-cdk/aws-apigateway:disableCloudWatchRole": true,
        "@aws-cdk/core:enablePartitionLiterals": true,
        "@aws-cdk/aws-events:eventsTargetQueueSameAccount": true,
        "@aws-cdk/aws-iam:standardizedServicePrincipals": true,
        "@aws-cdk/aws-ecs:disableExplicitDeploymentControllerForCircuitBreaker": true
      }
    }
```

I'm just executing `cdk synth` with no parameters.

Comment: How are you compiling the Typescript?  Does your `cdk.json` include a `build` command?

Comment: Hi. I wasn't specifically compiling the TypeScript on ```cdk synth``` as I assumed that the CDK was doing it (as my CDK code is written in TypeScript). There was no build step in my cdk.json file. After your suggestion I added "build": "npx tsc" into it. It hasn't affected the issue though.

Comment: I made a little progress. If I create the .d.ts file under node_modules/@types then the CDK sees it. Eg \node_modules\@types\mg-api-js\mg-api-js.d.ts.
This isn't really workable though for team sharing reasons. When I create a folder /types and put that file in, then include /types in tsconfig.json --> typeRoots, it fails again. I'm wondering if CDK has its own tsconfig somewhere it's using. I haven't been able to find anything.

Comment: The CDK CLI is written in TS, but is app-language agnostic.  It performs no TS/JS build actions on your code beyond the ones you have given it in the `cdk synth --app` command and `cdk.json`, as far as I know.  Do you have a standard project structure?  What is your `tsconfig.json` and `cdk.json` and `cdk synth` command?

Comment: I understand that you can develop for the CDK with multiple languages. Having said that, I'm writing my CDK infrastructure code in TypeScript. I presumed that at some point it would be compiling it. I've updated the question with my config files. I was thinking, I could probably put my .d.ts file in a folder which is excluded from TypeScript compilation (but still outside of node_modules for ease of editing) then modify 'package.json' --> 'scripts/build' to copy that file into /node_modules/@types before compiling. Seems a bit hacky though, and you'd also have to build before synthing.

Comment: For all languages, the CDK CLI does what you tell it (`--build`, then `--app`).  Does `npx ts-node --prefer-ts-exts bin/LeopardGeotabApp.ts` run without error on its own?  How about `node ./path/to/LeopardGeotabApp.js`?

Comment: Thanks @fedonev, that did the trick. Those didn't run on their own, but I hooked in to the app setting to temporarliy copy the d.ts file into node_modules/@types. The synth now works. A little hacky... but does the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got around this by modifying `cdk.json`

```
{
  "app": "cp ./types/mg-api-js.d.ts ./node_modules/@types/ && npx ts-node --prefer-ts-exts bin/LeopardGeotabApp.ts && rm ./node_modules/@types/mg-api-js.d.ts",
....
}
```

If I didn't delete the file after the ts-node step, then if I ran `tsc` on its own it would fail because of the duplication of the module in the .d.ts file.

Answer (score 3):

The underlying issue is that CDK uses [ts-node](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node) to compile and execute your TypeScript at run-time. It makes certain optimizations under the hood to improve the speed of compilation. One of these compilation tricks is that it does not eagerly load `files`, `include` or `exclude` by default and resolves dependencies by `import` and references. This presents an issue for custom global type declarations.

Fortunately there is a solution that is documented in the `ts-node` [README](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node#missing-types). It recognizes custom type declarations folders that you specify in `typeRoots`, **under the condition**, that you structure the folder as **type packages**.
`ts-node` **will not** recognize loose type declaration files (`./types/*.d.ts`), which I believe is the root cause of your issue.

#### Solution

`cdk.json`

```
"compilerOptions" {
  ...
  "typeRoots": [
    "./node_modules/@types"
    "./types",
  ],
}
```

`Folder Structure`

```
<project_root>/
-- tsconfig.json
-- types/
  -- <module_name>/
    -- index.d.ts
```

Apart from these changes, **no modifications** need to be performed to the `cdk.json` file

> **Note:** This response is my interpretation of the documentation solution from the `ts-node` [README](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node#missing-types). Please feel free refer to it for more information on the issue