# I have a problem setting up Styled components with Typescript and React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components, vite

I split my components into two files. Index.tsx and Style.js. I keep my styles in Style.js to keep the index file clean.

When I try to import my styled component from Style.js i get the following error:

```bash
Could not find a declaration file for module './Style'. '/Users/sjoerdvermeijden/Sites/react-vite-typescript-todo/src/components/Footer/Style.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

This is what the import looks like:

```js
import { FooterWrapper } from "./Style";
```

This is what the styles look like:

```js
import styled from "styled-components";

export const FooterWrapper = styled.div`
  padding: 25px 0;
  background: var(--darkgray);
  color: white;
`;
```

These are the modules i have installed to get styled components working:

```
npm i -D @types/styled-components
npm i styled-components
```

Comment: Maybe duplicated. Have a look to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41292559/could-not-find-a-declaration-file-for-module-module-name-path-to-module-nam

Answer (score 0):

change your `Style.js` to  `.ts` and also type your exported `FooterWrapper`:

```
export const FooterWrapper: ReactNode // or JSX.Element
```

Answer (score -1):

Change the file extension from .js to .jsx

Answer (score -1):

I noticed that you're facing some difficulties setting up Styled Components with TypeScript and React. I've encountered a similar issue in the past and found a solution that worked well for me. I've created a template that combines Tailwind CSS, TypeScript, and Styled Components. Feel free to modify it by adding or removing any dependencies to suit your project's requirements.

[tsdx](https://github.com/walifile/tsdx-tailwind-typescript-component-library)

I've tested this template, and it successfully wokring with Styled Components with TypeScript and React.

I hope this template helps you resolve the issues you're facing.Good luck!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34356052)