# is there any solutions for react-scrollable-picker in reactjs with type script?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am using a react-scrollable-picker from the https://ayame30.github.io/react-scrollable-picker/

but it shows an error like

Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-scrollable-picker'. '/directory/node_modules/react-scrollable-picker/lib/react-scrollable-picker.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.     Try `npm i --save-dev @types/react-scrollable-picker` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'react-scrollable-picker';`

again i try **npm i --save-dev @types/react-scrollable-picker** but looks like registry not found, how i can resolved this issue.?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could add you own declaration file as per plan C in [this](https://medium.com/@steveruiz/using-a-javascript-library-without-type-declarations-in-a-typescript-project-3643490015f3) post.
Also check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41292559/could-not-find-a-declaration-file-for-module-module-name-path-to-module-nam?rq=1) post on stackoverflow.