# Can not import yup in react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native, yup

I was taking the CodeWithMosh react native course and in the course I was supposed to use yup for validation however even though I installed the same version which is 0.28.5 of yup as in the course I got this error when importing...

`import * as Yup from "yup"`

but I got this error :-

Could not find a declaration file for module 'yup'

then it says try `npm i --save-dev @types/yup`

so I tried doing that but it still didn't work

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not find a declaration file for module 'module-name'. '/path/to/module-name.js' implicitly has an 'any' type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41292559/could-not-find-a-declaration-file-for-module-module-name-path-to-module-nam)

Comment: No I've already seen it it doesn't solve the issue for some reason

Comment: Try the second answer where you create your own declarations.d.ts

Comment: just tried that for some reason that solves the error but I can't get any properties of yup