# Error when trying to import 'angular-tree-component-amphinicy' in Angular project

Tags: angular, typescript, error-handling, type-definition

I'm encountering an error when I try to import 'angular-tree-component-amphinicy' in my Angular project. The error message mentions a missing declaration file, and I couldn't find a repository for type definitions.

Here's the specific error message:
"Could not find a declaration file for module 'angular-tree-component-amphinicy'. '.../node_modules/angular-tree-component-amphinicy/karma.conf.js' implicitly has an 'any' type. Try `npm i --save-dev @types/angular-tree-component-amphinicy` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'angular-tree-component-amphinicy';`"

I've tried installing '@types/angular-tree-component-amphinicy' as suggested, but it didn't resolve the issue. Since there doesn't seem to be a repository for type definitions for this module, what can I do to fix this error and use 'angular-tree-component-amphinicy' in my Angular project?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKA3a.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41292559/could-not-find-a-declaration-file-for-module-module-name-path-to-module-nam

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.