# Could not find module for Gatsby/TypeScript site on Vercel

Tags: typescript, gatsby, vercel

I have a test Gatsby site. The source code is [here](https://gitlab.com/datawookie/gatsby-whimsyweb/-/tree/18-vercel). I have converted my `gatsby-node.js` to `gatsby-node.ts`. All of the JavaScript files below `src/` have also been converted to TypeScript.

The site works fine in the following scenarios:

- local development server;
- local production server (build then serve); and
- deploying on Netlify (live site is [here](https://gatsby-whimsyweb-17-babel.netlify.app/1.2/)).

However, when I deploy to Vercel I get an error. I get the same error when I try to build locally using `vercel build`.

```
gatsby-node.ts:4:29 - error TS2306: File 'gatsby-whimsyweb/gatsby-node.ts.__vercel_builder_backup__.ts' is not a module.
4 import * as gatsbyNode from './gatsby-node.ts.__vercel_builder_backup__.ts';
gatsby-node.ts:6:15 - error TS2306: File 'gatsby-whimsyweb/gatsby-node.ts.__vercel_builder_backup__.ts' is not a module.
6 export * from './gatsby-node.ts.__vercel_builder_backup__.ts';
```

This error makes sense: there is no file called `gatsby-node.ts.__vercel_builder_backup__.ts`. But there is a file generated called `gatsby-node.ts.__vercel_builder_backup__.js` (the difference being in the final extension). Either I'm generating a file with the wrong extension (in which case, how do I change that?) or I'm trying to import a file with the wrong extension (again, how do I change this?).

An earlier (JavaScript version) of the site worked fine on Vercel too. It's only since trying to convert to TypeScript that things have gone awry.

In the interests of full disclosure, I don't know an awful lot about JavaScript or TypeScript. I am working on this project with the intention of learning.

I have scoured StackOverflow for help. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41292559/could-not-find-a-declaration-file-for-module-module-name-path-to-module-nam) was helpful to resolve an earlier issue. But now I'm stuck and have not made any progress for a while.