# Npm packages typescript declarations

Tags: typescript, npm-package

I have developed a tool [here](https://github.com/ae-creator/CosmosJS/tree/fix-declarations) to facilitate my development with bun.sh using workspaces that will be used as npm package however I have 2 problems,

When I bun install the 'core' packages from npm and test a sample, I get this error:

```
Could not find a declaration file for module '@cosmoosjs/core', index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41307319/15431338), but it doesn't work

The second problem is that when I try to build the typescript declarations for the hono package [here](https://github.com/ae-creator/CosmosJS/tree/fix-declarations/packages/hono-openapi-adapter), it crashes and can't load them because it refers to the other module via a workspace. I can't build the declarations but I can build the project.